# OP deleted question with multiple answers, How?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, answered-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518441/modal-window-is-always-visible) has two answers. I was trying to add a comment, when I couldn't. 
I realised the question had been deleted by the OP.

According to the meta [*how does deleting work what can cause a post to be deleted*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that), a question with multiple answers cannot be deleted by the OP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the answers was deleted by the answerer.

That left one remaining answer with no upvotes and the OP was then able to delete the question on that basis.

Comment: That sucks :( - what a time waster

Comment: Vote to undelete it, if you think it's worth it. Two other undelete votes will get it back.

Comment: I would if I was sure that _material_ did not have its own way of showing modal divs. I was just surprised that he could delete it at all