# Why a question with answers can be deleted by the author?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Recently I answered a question in one of the Stack Exchange sites, the author came to accept and comment the answer. However, after a while he undid the accept and erased the question, erasing my answer together.

I am aware of how exclusions work<sup>[[1]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/310559)[[2]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266169/310559)</sup>, but I would like to know what the reason is to allow a user, regardless of their reputation, to delete a question and together answers that are not their own? Why is an answer without votes considered to be an "invalid response" by the system, to the extent that it allows the questioner to exclude it together?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reasoning to allow authors to remove the question with non-positive-scoring answers is to allow authors of bad questions with bad answers to remove the thing all-together. There is no need for other users to be involved: crap removed, case closed.

That reasoning doesn't work for questions with fresh answers or in a tag with just little voting. And that should stop in my opinion. We should not allow authors to remove their question when there are fresh answers in, for example for a day or so. This will give the community the opportunity to vote as it seems necessary.

Comment: What did you mean by "fresh answers"? The mentioned question was deleted 3 hours after my reply. Something that should not happen happened in this case then?

Comment: That is fresh, right?

Comment: I think so, but it did not stop the question from being excluded.

Comment: Since it didn't have a positive-scoring answer it could be deleted, as explained. I propose to change that.

Comment: The system actually only allows deletion if there is a *single* non-upvoted answer. The moment there are two answers, they can't delete it anymore regardless of score.

Comment: @animuson But there could be a period of "lack", as grace period in edit posts. I had the job of responding and saw my answer being deleted without opportunity to be seen and voted on in a short time.